# Hide C# Console App Window When Started by Task Scheduler

Tags: c#, windows-7, scheduled-tasks, console-application

I have searched google for this and read some resources but I wasn't able to find a good answer.  Does anyone know how to prevent the console app window from opening when it is started by the task scheduler?

Ref.  https://www.google.com/search?q=task+scheduler+hide+console+window&aq=f&oq=task+scheduler+hide+console+window&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l2j62.7404&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change the `output type to Windows application` will solve your problem

Goto : Project - >Project Properties

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot; but how will that solve the problem?  Will it run it minimized or will it run in the background or something?

Comment: @user1477388: It runs like normal but it does not show any screens on front end..

Answer (score 11):

[image: Check Hidden checkbox]Check Hidden checkbox, and check the "Run whether user is logged on or not" check box and executable will run in the background.

Comment: The "Hidden" option on the task, will only hide the task in the task manager GUI. It does nothing to how the Actions are executed. (You can view Hidden Tasks by View > Show Hidden Tasks).

Comment: @Wasted_Coder, you are right.  to hidden console window, just change output type to windows application or else check "Run whether user is logged on or not" and check "Do not store password"

Answer (score 5):

If you have access to the code/solution, On **ProjectProperties set Output Type as Windows Application**.

Comment: You answered this 6 minutes before the other guy, but he included a screenshot which would probably be helpful to other users who may find this resource.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

As a simple partial solution, you can start your application minimized from a task scheduler.

```
start /min <full path to your app>.exe
```

It would be present in task bar, but it's main window would not be visible unless user clicks it in the task bar.

Comment: How do I declare this via the Task Scheduler UI?

Comment: Just type it into executable program textbox. If "start" would not work by itself, try executing it in a command line interpreter. like this: `cmd /c start /min <full path to your app>.exe`

Answer (score 2):

Set "*Run only when user is logged in*" to be **visible**.
Set "*Run whether user is logged on or not*" to be always **hidden** regardless of the setting of the "Hidden" checkbox.

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722152.aspx

Comment: what is that even supposed to mean? "visible" and "hidden" do not make any sense, in this context. Feel free to use a proper translator and re-phrase your sentence

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check the checkbox that says 'Hidden' in the 'General' tab of the Task scheduler if you want a quick fix.