# Taskeng.exe popup up

Tags: c#, taskscheduler

I have created and registered a task as below

```
ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(
    taskname, 
    td,
    TaskCreation.CreateOrUpdate, 
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"], 
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"], 
    TaskLogonType.InteractiveTokenOrPassword);
```

The problem is that when the task is executed from the task manager it keeps bringing a black "Taskeng.exe" window which opens up and closes automatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set a Windows scheduled task to run in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568736/how-do-i-set-a-windows-scheduled-task-to-run-in-the-background)

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745195/hide-c-sharp-console-app-window-when-started-by-task-scheduler